# Fix conflict between rails executable "rails" and railties

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rvm

Trying to switch from rails 3.2.13 to 3.1, using RVM 1.22.3.

Using ruby 1.9.3.

Did the following:

```
$ rvm gemset create rails31
gemset created rails31  => /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails31
$ rvm 1.9.3-p429@rails31
$ gem install -v3.1 rails
```

After fetching and successfully installing many gems, I am prompted with this:

```
rails's executable "rails" conflicts with railties
Overwrite the executable? [yN]
```

I chose no.

Then

```
$ rails -v
Rails 3.1.0
```

Am I fully set up? How do I resolve this conflict if I need to?

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to resolve gem version conflicts:

1. use version of rails when generating new application: `rails _3.1.0_ new` - this will make sure that your selected version is used to generate new project. This works only in simple scenarios and will not help with problems with "wrong gem version already loaded".
2. use `Gemfile` to tell bundler which version of rails to use:

   ```
   source "http://rubygems.org"
   gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
   ```

   and then all commands you prefix with `bundle exec` like `bundle exec rails` will be executed using version of `rails` stored in `Gemfile` - as you use RVM it comes with gem [rubygems-bundler](https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler) installed and it does load `Bundler` for you so it is not needed to prefix commands with `bundle exec` if you have `Gemfile` and proper gem (rails) version is installed.